# Slack api ratelimit

Tags: google-apps-script, slack-api

I'm trying to collect information from the custom field with Slack API `users.profile.get` + Google apps script and faced with the fact that after several iterations slack API starts to respond

```
{ ok: false, error: 'ratelimited' }
```

[image: ratelimit error]

In slack API docs are written that rate limit error should return **429**, but `getResponseCode()` always returns **200**, which is the answer, that everything is OK.

The situation is complicated by the fact that there is a custom rate limit for `users.profile.get` and I can't just use `Utilities.sleep()`

```
for ( var i = 0; i < userslist.length; i++ ) {
    sheet.getRange( i + 1, 1 ).setValue( userslist[ i ].id );

    citypayload = {
          "token"          : token
        , "user"           : userslist[i].id
        , "include_labels" : true
    };

    response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
          "https://slack.com/api/users.profile.get"
        , { "method":"get", "payload":citypayload }
    ); //request for custom field

    Logger.log( response.getResponseCode() );

    cityData = JSON.parse( response );

    try {
        sheet.getRange( i + 1, 7 ).setValue( cityData.profile.fields."FieldID".value );
    } //bots havent required field and cycle stops with error
    catch( e ){

    };

    sheet.getRange( i + 1, 2 ).setValue( userslist[ i ].deleted       );
    sheet.getRange( i + 1, 3 ).setValue( userslist[ i ].real_name     );
    sheet.getRange( i + 1, 4 ).setValue( userslist[ i ].profile.title );
    sheet.getRange( i + 1, 5 ).setValue( userslist[ i ].profile.phone );
    sheet.getRange( i + 1, 6 ).setValue( userslist[ i ].profile.skype );
    console.log( cityData );
```

Comment: https://api.slack.com/docs/rate-limits

Comment: yep, I already read this and wrote that the 'Logger.log( response.getResponseCode() );'  returns the code 200, instead of 429